# Getting clicked point coordinates in 3D figure Matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry, matlab-figure, figure, surface

I have a 3D figure in Matlab, let's assume it's sphere. What I need, is to get the `X`, `Y`, `Z` values of the point on surface, that I click with the mouse.

```
r = 10;
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(50); 
X2 = X * r;
Y2 = Y * r;
Z2 = Z * r;
figure();
props.FaceColor = 'texture';
props.EdgeColor = 'none';
props.FaceLighting = 'phong';
sphere = surf(X2,Y2,Z2,props);
axis equal
hold on

clicked_point = [?,?,?];
```

[image]

So in this example I want the `clicked_point` to be equal to `[-3.445,-7.32,5.878]`.

I've tried with such solution:

```
clear all;
close all;
r = 10;
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(50);
X2 = X * r;
Y2 = Y * r;
Z2 = Z * r;
fig = figure();
props.FaceColor = 'texture';
props.EdgeColor = 'none';
props.FaceLighting = 'phong';
sphere = surf(X2,Y2,Z2,props);
axis equal

dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig);
set(dcm_obj,'DisplayStyle','datatip',...
'SnapToDataVertex','off','Enable','on')
c_info = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);

while length(c_info) < 1
    datacursormode on
    c_info = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);
end
```

But after that I can't even click on the sphere to display any data on figure. How can I get `X`, `Y`, `Z` in script? If not, how can I detect that the mouse click has already occured in Matlab?

Comment: This? https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94353-how-can-i-select-multiple-points-using-the-data-cursor-and-export-the-coordinates-to-the-matlab-work, https://uk.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.logicanalyzer.getcursorinfo.html

Comment: @AnderBiguri no, in the soluton under your link, you need to call the code manually from console, after mouse clicking. I want my script to detect that the click has occured and then get the values.

Comment: You just want to combine that with a callback (google "MATLAB click figure event") https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/capturing-mouse-clicks.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear whether you want the `clicked_point` variable to reside in the base workspace or if that is going to be part of a GUI.

I'll give you a solution for the base workspace.

The trick is to just add the bit of code you need to the `UpdateFcn` of the `datacursormode` object.

Save a function `getClickedPoint.m` somewhere visible on your MATLAB path:

```
function output_txt = getClickedPoint(obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
output_txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1),4)],...
    ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)]};

% If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
if length(pos) > 2
    output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ',num2str(pos(3),4)];
end

assignin('base','clicked_point',pos)
```

All this code is actually a copy of the default function used by data cursors. The only modifications are:

- I changed the name (obviously you want it to be unique)
- I added the last line of code

This last line of code use [`assignin`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) to transfer the position of the cursor into a variable (named `clicked_point`) in the `base` workspace.

Armed with that, keep your code which generate the sphere (although I recommend you change the name of the surface object to something else than `sphere` as this is a built in MATLAB function), and we just have to modify the `datacursormode` object to instruct it to use our `getClickedPoint` function:

```
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(50);
r = 10 ; X2 = X * r; Y2 = Y * r; Z2 = Z * r;
fig = figure ;
hs  = surf(X2,Y2,Z2,'FaceColor','texture','EdgeColor','none','FaceLighting','phong');
axis equal

%% Assign custom update function to dcm
dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig);
set(dcm_obj,'SnapToDataVertex','off','Enable','on','UpdateFcn',@getClickedPoint)
```

---

Now the first time you click on the sphere, the variable `clicked_point` will be created in the workspace with the coordinates of the point. And every time you click again on the sphere the variable will be updated:

[image]

---

If this is to be applied with a GUI, use the same technique but instead of `assignin`, I would recommend to use the [`setappdata`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) function. (you can read [Share Data Among Callbacks](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html) to have details about how this works.)