# Is there a way to get the three dimensional coordinate from a click LiDAR scan (pcd file)?

Tags: matlab, lidar

I want to get the coordinates of a click from the user relative to the axes of the pcshow function. For example, if I have a scan of a room, I wanted to be able to capture a click on the wall of the room and get the coordinates.

I have tried using the method of doing this according to [Getting clicked point coordinates in 3D figure Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65109922/getting-clicked-point-coordinates-in-3d-figure-matlab) but it doesnt seem to work on pcshow.